# Interpolation of geocoordinates

Tags: geolocation, geometry, geo

I'd like to do the equivalent of linear interpolation in geo space.

e.g.

in Cartesian 2D space I do

```
[x,y] = [x0,y0]+([x1,y1]-[x0,y0])*d

with d={0..1.0}
```

to calculate any point between [x0,y0] and [x1,y1]. How do I proceed in geo coordinates with  latitude,longitude ?

Thanx

Comment: iteratively, starting from `p0`, calculate a bearing from current point to `p1` and perform a small step in this direction, resulting next current point, until `p1` is reached. No direct formula exists since bearing on ellipsoid is also calculated iteratively.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I'd be quite happy with the spherical approximation.

Comment: what is the maximum length between both points p0 and p1 in the app you need thar? some kilometers or (half) around the world?

Comment: everything in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [Slerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) is what you need.